# Proving that $S^1$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I want to prove that $S^1 = \{ (x,y): x^2+y^2=1\}$ is a closed subset in $\mathbb{R}^2$ in that following manner: I want to show that $(S^1)^c = R^2\setminus S^1$ is open. For this let $a=(a_1,a_2)\in (S^1)^c$ so $a_1^2+a_2^2>1$ or $a_1^2+a_2^2<1$. Let $a_1^2+a_2^2>1$. Let $r = d(a,S^1)$ and let's consider the open ball $B(a,r)$ and $x=(x_1,x_2)\in B(a,r)$. I'm stuck here to show that $x_1^2+x_2^2>1$.

Any help? (Obs: $d(x,S) = \inf\{d(x,y): y\in S\}$)

Comment: Isn’t it easier to take a convergent sequence in $S^1$ and prove that the limit is in $S^1$?

Comment: Maybe, but I want to be restricted in this way of proceeding since I yet "don't know" what is a sequence.

Comment: Oof. That sounds rough. Do you “know” what it means for functions to be continuous?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I'm sorry, I just meant that the study of sequences is ahead in my classes, though we're already seen continuity

Comment: To finish your proof you need to observe that the distance from $a$ to the origin is $1 + r$, then use the triangle inequality on the distances from $(x_1, x_2)$ to the origin and to $a$.

Comment: As a general note, this kind of argument tends to involve the triangle inequality.

Comment: Topological argument: $S^1$ is a continuous image of $[0,1]$ and therefore compact, since $\mathbb R^2$ is Hausdorff, that implies that $S^1$ is closed.

Comment: In case mapping $[0,1]$ continuously onto $S^1$ isn’t obvious to you, like it wasn’t to me when I first encountered it: http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masbm/Manifolds/quotient.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will denote by $d$ the usual distance in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $A=(a_1,a_2)$, let $D=\frac A{\sqrt{{a_1}^2+{a_2}^2}}$, let $r=d(A,D)$ (it is equal to your $r$), let $B=(0,0)$ and let $C$ be an arbitrary point of $B(A,r)$. I will prove that $d(C,B)>1$. In order to that, note that $B$, $D$, and $A$ are colinear, with $D$ between $A$ and $B$; therefore, $d(B,A)=d(B,D)+d(D,A)=1+d(D,A)$. On the other hand, by the triangle inequality,$$d(B,A)\leqslant d(B,C)+d(C,A),$$and this is equivalent to$$1+d(D,A)\leqslant d(B,C)+d(C,A).$$Therefore\begin{align}d(C,B)&=d(B,C)\\&\geqslant1+d(D,A)-d(C,A)\\&=1+r-d(C,A)\text{ (because $C\in B(A,r)$)}\\&>1.\end{align}

Answer (score 7):

It would be easier if you note $f \colon \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $(x, y) \mapsto x^2+y^2$ is continuous and $S^1 = f^{-1}( \{1\})$.

Comment: Proving $f$ is continuous seems about as hard or harder than proving OP's question though.

Comment: @MartianInvader why ?  because , it's polynomial in each variable , let  $f_{1} : (x,y) \to x$ and $f_{2} : (x,y) \to y$ ,  $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are linear in a space of finite dimension hence they are continuous and $f(x,y)=f_{1}(x,y))^{2}+f_{2}(x,y)^{2}$  is clearly continuous as sum of two continuous function

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way. Consider the map from the plane to the line given by $x^2+y^2$, and show that it's continuous. The circle is just the inverse image of $1$ under this continuous map and hence is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two random arguments for fun, I think that they work.

Identify $\mathbb C$ with $\mathbb R^2$. Note that $[0,2 \pi]$ is closed in $\mathbb R^1$. Endow it with the subspace topology.

Consider  $f:[0,2 \pi]  \to \mathbb C$ given by $f(x)=e^{ix}$. Notice that its image is $S^1 \subset \mathbb C$.

1. this is a continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space, and hence closed, so $S^1$ is closed.
2. Since $f(x)=f(y) \iff x=y$ or $x,y=0,1$. In other words, this map identifies the points $0,2 \pi \in [0,2 \pi]$. But then this induces a map $\tilde{f}:[0,2 \pi]/{\sim} \to S^1 \subset \mathbb C$, where $x \sim y \iff x,y=0,1$. Indeed, $\tilde{f}$ is a homeomorphism, and so $S^1$ is closed in $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the triangle inequality :$ \lvert x+y\rvert \le \lvert x\rvert +\lvert y\rvert $, in the form $\lvert x-y \rvert\ge \lvert x \rvert -\lvert  y \rvert $.  Use it on the triangle formed by $x ,a $ and $(0,0) $...

Note:  $ \lvert x- a\rvert   \lt r $.  And $\lvert a\rvert = 1+r $.  Therefore,  $\lvert x \rvert =\lvert a-(a-x)\rvert \ge \lvert a\rvert -\lvert a-x\rvert  \gt 1+r-r=1$...

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $(S^1)^c$ is open it suffices that for any $a\in (S^1)^c$ there exists some $z>0$ such that $B(a,z)\cap S^1$ is empty. We do not need to take $z=d(a,S^1).$

Let $a=(a_1,a_2)$ with $a_1^2+a_2^2=1+s\ne 1$.

If $z>0$ and  $z$ is small enough that $\max (|a_1z|,|a_2z|, |z|^2)<|s|/6$ then for any $(a_1+d_1,a_2+d_2)\in B(a,z)$ we have $|d_1|<z$ and $|d_2|<z,$ $$\text { so }\quad |2a_1d_1+2a_2d_2+d_1^2+d_2^2|<|s|$$  $$\text {so } \quad  (a_1+d_1)^2+(a_2+d_2)^2=(1+s)+(2a_1d_1+2a_2d_2+a_1^2+d_2^2)\ne 1.$$

Comment: Assuming that $d(a,S^1)>0$ for every $a\in (S^1)^c$ is assuming that $(S^1)^c$ is open . What is needed is to show that for $a\in (S^1)^c$ there exists $z>0$ such that  $d(a,S^1)\geq z,$  equivalently that $B(a.z)\cap S^1=\phi.$

Comment: The method in my A is basically the method of showing that $f((x,y))=x^2+y^2$ is continuous from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R .$ Since $\{1\}$ is a closed subset of $ \Bbb R$ and $f $ is continuous, therefore $f^{-1}\{1\}=S^1$ is closed in $\Bbb R^2.$